# Previous Images turning into Current Image in Function that returns view

Tags: swiftui

```swift
HStack {
    Spacer()
    if let capturedImage = camera.capturedImage {
        Spacer()
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
            .background(.clear)
            .foregroundStyle(.clear)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 200)
            .overlay {
                Image(uiImage: capturedImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner and I have a problem with this. This code is in a function that returns a view. I call the function in a scrollview. The capturedImage is the image taken by the user camera.

The issue is that when there is a new capturedImage, all of the previous images in the scrollview are updated to the latest one.

I tried making an array but I had the same problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then [edit] your question.

Comment: You need to show more code.